# make nodejs request from server timeout

Tags: node.js

I have to check if a URL is working or not on the server side. But some URLs take so much time to respond. I want to set a timeout and if a URL do not responds in that time the URL will be considered not working.

I am using npm request library. here is how i tried doing it. But it keep waiting for the response.

```
    request({
            url: 'https://httpbin.org/ip',
            method: 'GET',
            proxy,
            timeout: 2000 // this option is not working
        }, function(err, response) {
            if(!err && response.statusCode === 200) resolve(proxy);
            else reject(false);
        });
```

**Update**

My intention here is not to check the URL. I'm checking here if the proxy is working or not. In the above code the object proxy contains a proxy value that it gets from free-proxy-list.net

Comment: There is nothing to clarify here. The question is simple. I am just asking if why timout option is not working. Please consider commenting before down voting